# Rubygem: ruby gem to process language

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, nlp

I'm trying to find a ruby gem that allows me to process English.

I wonder if there's a gem that can detect a subject in a phrase and its predicate easily.

If there's not a gem, is there an easy algorithm in ruby to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby NLP Libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776361/ruby-nlp-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key search phrase you need is Natural Language Processing, or NLP. Here are some older SO questions on the topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776361/ruby-nlp-libraries

[Natural Language Processing in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999410/natural-language-processing-in-ruby)