# Detecting Elements of Sentence In Ruby

Tags: ruby, nlp, linguistics

My aim is detecting simple elements in any sentence such as verb, noun or adjective. Is there any gem in Ruby for achieving that? For example:

> They elected him president yesterday.

Output:

```
["subject","verb", "object", "predicative", adverbial"]
```

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999410/natural-language-processing-in-ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the only natural language processing options for Ruby that I know of.

- [Treat](https://github.com/louismullie/treat)
- [Stanford Core NLP](https://github.com/louismullie/stanford-core-nlp)
- [Open NLP](https://github.com/louismullie/open-nlp)

Interestingly, they are all by the same person.

**EDIT**
Here is one more option that I found. It's a tutorial on *n-gram* analysis.

[Natural Language Processing with Ruby: n-grams](http://www.sitepoint.com/natural-language-processing-ruby-n-grams/)

Comment: The Ruby wrappers are from the same person, but the libraries behind are not!

Comment: I tried both Open NLP and Treat and Treat literally beats Open NLP in nameTagger. It's very extensive.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [engtagger](https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger) with good success in the past.  It's ported from a Perl program called `Lingua::EN::Tagger`.  It takes a bit of work to get it to do what you want, but I think it's the best tool available for this application (at least at the moment).

Comment: does it give the elements as array or just with the tags?

Comment: depends - you can get them as a hash with the frequency as value, but if you fiddle just a bit you could very easily make the output anything you want

Comment: Part-of-Speech tagging is good in engtagger but it's noun phrase method isn't really dependable.